# OK button grayed out in QGIS field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I'm seeking to calculate the area of New York City neighborhoods delineated in [this](https://data.beta.nyc/dataset/pediacities-nyc-neighborhoods/resource/35dd04fb-81b3-479b-a074-a27a37888ce7) data set. I've imported the file into QGIS and set the layer to editable. But when I attempt to calculate the area of each neighborhood in the field calculator, the OK button is grayed out:

[image]

Following advice given in previous threads, I've exported the file to a .shp file and encountered the same problem. I've also checked my permissions and I'm allowed to read and write with it.

Anyone know why this is happening? The preview indicates that the area is calculating...

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify a Output field name