# "OK" button is grayed out in QGIS field calculator, despite troubleshooting

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am trying to add a new field to a shapefile layer (created in R) using the Field Calculator in the attribute table in QGIS. However, the "OK" button is grayed out and nothing I do will allow me to create a new field (or update an existing one).

Someone asked the same question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419842/ok-button-grayed-out-in-qgis-field-calculator) but I made sure I have the output field name specified, and it remains gray.

When I first noticed the issue I was not in edit mode, but the field calculator box displayed the message "You are editing information on this layer but the layer is currently not in edit mode. If you click OK, edit mode will automatically be turned on" - which implies that I should have been able to click OK anyway.

Here are the things I've tried, none of which have solved the problem:

- Toggling edit on before opening the attribute table
- Ensuring that I have permission to edit this file (I copied it to a folder on my laptop and made sure I have read and write permissions for the folder)
- Restarting QGIS and adding the shapefile in a new blank project
- Ensuring that the layer is not in read-only mode in QGIS Project Properties ("identifiable" and "searchable" are the only two boxes checked)
- Creating a new shapefile with the same R script and opening it in QGIS

I am using QGIS 3.32.0-Lima on a MacBook Air (M2 chip), MacOS Ventura 13.5.

Comment: Make sure the field name is given and the expression is valid == resolves to data type of the new field type. BTW, why not create the required fields in R?